# Does Entangling Shot involve one duration roll or one per target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does each target in the AoE of an [Entangling Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/ammunition/alchemical-cartridges/entangling-shot-cartridge) roll independently for the 2d4 rounds of entanglement, or does the PC roll one duration shared by all who fail the reflex save?

Answer (score 6):

### Roll once.

This is, as far as I know, not written down in the Core Rulebook. The reasons for doing so are:

1. It's more convenient.
2. The general understanding is that rolls other than the attack roll itself represent the variance present in the effectiveness of the *attack*. The variance in how well the attack affects each individual target is represented by saving throws (or damage reduction).
3. It has been established by decades of convention. (For damage rolls.)

It is not relevant to the rules scope of the Pathfinder RPG, but you may still be interested to know that this rule did turn out to be codified in the fourth edition of D&D.